# PHP execute bash scripts asynchronous

Tags: php, linux, bash, sh

I am trying to run bash scripts on PHP asynchronous, my current scripts waits until first script is executed before it starts to run the next one:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
  exec('php /var/www/index.php $(nmap -p 80 google.com)');
}
```

I found out to run async, i must put '&' at the end of my script to run it in foreground:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
  exec('php /var/www/index.php $(nmap -p 80 google.com) &');
}
```

This script will pass result of $(nmap -p 80 google.com) to my index.php and run itself in foreground. Problem is - i need to cancel that process once the script is finshed. I tried doing it like so:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
  exec('php /var/www/index.php $(nmap -p 80 google.com) $BASHPID &');
}
```

I pass a second parameter to index.php ($BASHPID) - process id of that bash script, then inside that index.php file, i run another exec command to kill that process. Problem is - it passes wrong process ID, and it doesn't kill the process in the end.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I would actually turn the whole thing around. Ie. create a queue of some sorts in which you can inject your request. Write 1 script that just keeps running, which checks the queue and performs the tasks + updates the response in the queue.   Then for your webpage, just write a continuous ajax request that checks if the job in the queue has been updated.

Comment: This has the added benefit that the code that executes the "exec" can have a seperate phi.ini (which allows 'exec') on CLI, whilst the "Web" version does not. This keeps things safer too.

Comment: I do not have an answer but this does not look very robust.

Comment: This cannot be the solution